# Why is my Partial View not loading the right content?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I have my partial View which contains

```
@model List<Destination>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
       @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Id)
       <div class="form-row">
           <div class="form-group col-md-10">
                <label>@Html.LabelFor(model => model[i].Path) ( @(i + 1) )</label>
                <input type="text" value=@Model[i].Path/>  
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].Path, new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" , title = "My custom error message")

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].Path)
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="deleteField(event, 
        '@Model[i].Id');">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                </button>
    }
```

I added the input which contains the value `@Model[i].Path`, because i receive a list, i can do adds and removes on the list. If i have a list of 3items when i remove the `index i=1`, it always removes the last index so it removes the last item. To test if the receive input is correct i added the input and yes the value is correct, but in the `textboxfor`, the value is not reloaded and contains the old value.

Second point even for the message error which is custom, for the first input of the list it is not reloaded to be the new custom message, for the added elements on the list the message is custom.

How can i fix these two problems, which seems like somethings is wrong between the server which sends the model and the time of populating the partial view. The objects are all correct.

Edit: To update the partial view, example to delete an element

```
public ActionResult SupprimerChampDestination(Destinations model, int idToDelete)
        {
            model.Path.RemoveAll(elementToDelete => elementToDelete.Id == idToDelete);
            ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = Constante.PrefixPartialViewDestination;
            return PartialView(Vues.Paths.Destination, model.Path);
        }
```

And the JS:

```
function deleteField(event, clickedId) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var model = $("#Form").serialize();
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("SupprimerChampDestination", "PathsController")',
                data: model + "&idToDelete=" + clickedId,
                success: function (response) {
                    debugger;
                    console.log(response);
                    $("#destinationMultiple").html(response);

                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
                    console.log(xhr.statusText);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
```

$("#destinationMultiple") is the div containing the partial view where i load the result.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us how you are including the partial view in your use case? When you use a partial view you need to pass it the appropriate viewmodel to the partial view.  if the type doesn't match the `model` in the partial view will be null.

Comment: @GlennFerrie edited answer, but the model received by the partial view is correct, it's the population that doesn't work well which is weird

Comment: Where are you persisting the changes to the list values? And is there any specific reason for the for loop as opposed to a foreach?

Comment: @melkisadek foreach doesnt bind the validations etc to the correct index, everything is linked to the first element

Comment: Where in the program flow are you trying to remove items from the list? There is nothing in your displayed partial code that removes an item. Also, can you post your rendered HTML?

Comment: @melkisadek edited answer, i have a button which calls a js function which does an ajax call

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. The Ajax call is meant to return data without reloading the page - how does the partial get parsed? The partial you're returning from the Ajax call has a model of `model.Path` but the partial is expecting a `List<Destination>`. Can you post all your code to show exactly what you're doing - including the parsed HTML from the page load and from after the Ajax call, please.